# No check in option before Add Document

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, file-upload, check-in

Document Library- It doesnt have the option to check in when I upload a file.
Usually close to the save button there is a check in option and noramlly if any of your column are required, you can't check in without feeling them.

Can I show the Content Type on this window ? 
so when a user is uploading a file they also can choose on of my  custom make content types ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display Check In in the upload file dialog, you can go to library settings->Versioning settings->select “Yes” for “Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?”.

To select the Document Type in the dialog, you can go to library settings->Advanced settings->select “Yes” for “Allow management of content types?”->return to library settings page->add your custom content type under Content types section, finally, when you upload the file, there will be a option for content type.

[image]

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately the content type is not showing in the Dialog even after creating a custom content type and following your steps. Please help me

Comment: Is there a way  that when the dialog box open the Contet Type is not has no default ( so it is blank ) bc this will make the users look into the content type option and choose the appropriate one.